# Set pan enable at runtime

Tags: android, touch, achartengine

I'm using achartengine. When first created I am disabling touch events. But I want to re enable them in runtime. Here is my code:

```
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
private GraphicalView graphView;
public void setFreeStyle(boolean isFree) {
        if (isFree) {
            mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
            mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
            mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
            graphView.repaint();
        } else {
            mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
            mRenderer.setInScroll(false);
            mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false);
            graphView.repaint();
        }
}
```

I think that I should update my GraphicalView somehow. But I couln't find how. I used "graphView.repaint();", but it doesn't seems to work.

----Edit----

I think touch events are re activating by this way. But pan isn't. I want to re activate panning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I don't know why but if you use " mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false,false); " in initialization, you can never re activate panning. So I tried to initialize differently:

```
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
    GraphicalView graphView;

public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {

... some initialization code ...

    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false); //first you should left x-axis pan enabled

    graphView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer,
                "HH:mm:ss");

    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false,false); //After you created GraphicalView you can disable pan                safely

    return graphView;

}
```

And the code that re enables/disables pan :

```
public void setFreeStyle(boolean isFree){
    if (isFree) {
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
        graphView.repaint();
    }else {
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false,false);
        graphView.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

**Edit:**

```
  public void setFreeStyle(boolean isFree)
    {
        if(isFree)
        {
            view.setClickable(true);
            mRen.setClickEnabled(true);
            mRen.setPanEnabled(true, true);
            mRen.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
            view.repaint();
        }
        else
        {
            view.setClickable(false);
            mRen.setClickEnabled(false);
            mRen.setPanEnabled(false, false);
            mRen.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
            view.repaint();
        }
    }
```

and

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                System.out.println("LINE GRAPH CLICKED ###");

            }
        });
```

Comment: When I set onClickListener like that, It works on tap. But app crashes when a long click occurs. And I want to browse through graph. When I override onClickListener, naturally browsing is being disabled.

Comment: See change in answer, I added a new line, and I don't get what do you mean by "browse through graph" ?

Comment: Sorry for my English. It is a little bit rusty. All I want is to re enable pan. Thanks to the last code you send, app doesn't crash anymore on long clicks. But pan still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it didn't work either. It crashes the app again. But I solved the problem. I'm posting it as an answer.